# ubuntu will not let me set login page background

Tags: login-screen, cinnamon

I want to change the background image of my Ubuntu (14.04) login screen, but Ubuntu doesn't display the changes. I tried changing the background in dconf-editor which resulted in there being no background just the vanilla Ubuntu color. And logging in resulted in the screen freezing in a kind of white noise mix of the login screen, after which I come in the desktop.

Then I tried it with Ubuntu tweak with no change.

I'm using the cinnamon desktop, I don't know if that may be the problem?

Anyone have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Use dconf-editor to change background, this should work.

Comment: If you read the question you can read that I was using dconf-editor but it still didn't work, thanks for contributing though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak will most probably work.

**Possible reasons of your problem:**

1. Permissions to your Image file is wrong.

   The Image file should have the following permissions:

   - Owner: Root 
     Access :Read and Write
   - Group: Root
     Access: Read-only
   - Others: Read-only
2. Your File location is not suitable

I strongly recommend you to copy your Image file to  `/usr/share/backgrounds`

**Step-wise Solution**

1. First of all, let's make it easy to open folders with Admin Privilege:

   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type (Enter Password if prompted):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install open-as-administrator
   nautilus -q
   ```

   Now you can open any folder with permission by right-clicking on the folder and choosing <kbd>open_as_Administrator</kbd> (Enter Password if prompted).

   [image: Screen shot]
2. Open the background folder with Admin Privilege.
3. Now <kbd>Copy</kbd> your image and <kbd>Paste</kbd> it to this folder.
4. Right click on the Image and go to <kbd>Properties</kbd>
5. Go to the <kbd>Permission</kbd> Tab and Change the permissions as listed above.

   [image: ScreenShot]
   (Note: Once you Open the folder as Admin, Owner will be shown as *Me* instead of *Root*)
6. Close the window.
7. Now Use `ubuntu-tweak` and select the file from the `Backgrounds` folder.
   (Assuming that you know to use Ubuntu Tweak).

Comment: Could Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Could you help the user even more by providing how to change those permissions how to copy it to the right directory?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ Fabby. The solution is Edited

Comment: *Now* it's a good answer, so upvoted!  **;-)** (Look at the edits I made)

Comment: Can you please activate the 2nd Screenshot ? Pic of Permission window will be helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks that did the job. "open-as-administrator" is a nice feature, I was using "sudo nautilus" in the terminal to do something similar.
It was the permissions that broke the camels back. I tried putting a file with hardly any permissions in the background folder and select that as background from tweak and broke the login screen, changing the permissions in a vertual terminal solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing Gnome desktop. I think its because these "themes" call for background from different places.

What I did:

- went to /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
- found the .png file that was my background (for me it was noise-texture.png)
- replaced that file with a background of my liking (keeping "noise-texture.png" name)

For you the directory would probably be more like `/usr/share/cinnamon-shell/theme`.

I believe this also depends on the display manager you are using. I was using GDM.

Comment: That would work only if you correctly set the permissions of the replacement file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause: the file you want to use as a background is not readable by 'others'.
Check the access rights of the file:

`> ls -l
total 21552
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1320 dec  5  2002 your_image`

It should have 'r' permissions for the group 'other' (as is the case here).

Comment: That indeed was the problem, as I'm something of a noob I would have to look up chmod and the correct codes (644) to change the premisions.
`sudo chmod 644 file_name.jpg` would have done the job